# Identify a text using CSS Selector embedded inside <Strong> which in turn is inside <label> tags

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a website in which I need to identify/read the text inside  and which in turn inside  tag as shown below:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 execution-data-container">
    <div>...</div>
    <div>
        <label>
            <Strong>Submitted</Strong>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
</div>
```

I prefer to use CSS Selector for that is our project preference.
I tried to do like this:

```
//div[@class='col-sm-4 execution-data-container']/div/div/label/Strong[text() = 'Completed']
```

and:

```
div.col-sm-4.execution-data-container > div > div > 
label.text()
```

and:

```
div.col-sm-4.execution-data-container > div > div > 
label[text()='Completed']
```

By building a CSS Selector, I want to obtain the text 'Submitted'.

Comment: Hi, please next time try to format your question correctly. It helps

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way to get the CSS Sector.See If this helps.

```
".col-sm-4 >div>div>div>label>strong"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't locate elements by contained text using CSS selectors. You can only do this using XPath.

Your XPath is pretty close... you just had an extra `/div/` level that wasn't needed.

```
//div[@class='col-sm-4 execution-data-container']/div/label/strong[.='Submitted']
```

If you really want to use a CSS selector, you can use

```
String status = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.col-sm-4.execution-data-container > div > label > strong")).getText();
```

which returns 'Submitted'.